# Using button.class to submit ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a form which submits couple of fields to MySQL as well as to an ajax

This is the ajax I am using

```
$(function() {
  $(".CommentSend").click(function() {
  var comment = $("input#Comment").val();
  var user = $("input#InverrtedUser").val();
  var name = $("input#SendTaskName").val();
  var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&user=' + user + '&name=' + name;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some_php_file.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      //display message back to user here
    }
  });
  return false;
    });
  });
```

The form looks like

```
<form name="CommentForm" method="POST" action="" id="CommentForm">
///some fields
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

if I change the button class like this the ajax execute correctly

```
<button type="submit" class="CommentSend" >Submit</button>
```

However, the form is not submitted.
If I use id in the button like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="CommentSend">Submit</button>
```

And change the ajax to

```
$("#CommentSend").click(function() {
```

The form is submitted, but the ajax is not executed. And i cannot seems to spot whats wrong and what I am missing. So, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The last line of your click handler is `return false;`.  That's going to "cancel" the click of the button, which is a submit button, so the submit will not happen.

Comment: You can not submit a form and make an Ajax call at the same time. Ajax call will not make it because the form submission will cancel the HTTP request. You need to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: Why are you trying to make *two* requests to the server with the same button click?  What's the goal here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  // using an id selector here
  // if you need it to be a class
  // change it to '.CommentSend'      // include the event
  $("#CommentSend").on('click', function(e) {
    var comment = $("input#Comment").val();
    var user = $("input#InverrtedUser").val();
    var name = $("input#SendTaskName").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some_php_file.php",
      data: { comment: comment, user: user, name: name },
      success: function() {
        //display message back to user here
        
        
        // if you want the form to submit now that the ajax is done
        // you can submit the form logically
        $(e.target).closest('form').submit();
      }
    });
    
    // leave this so it cancels the button click
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Will `return false` work here? I usually use `e.preventDefault()` that the top of the click handler myself.

Comment: return false does the preventDefault logic, as well as the stopPropagation logic.  In that sense it's a bit heavy handed, but it's what the user originally had so I left it. @DelightedD0D

Comment: @DelightedD0D id vs class selector on your binding

Comment: DelightedD0D, I think it is something bootstrap related to "btn btn-success"

Comment: @Taplar, I have tried your version, but it doesn't work either

Comment: Can you show me by updating your question, or throwing it in a fiddle?  @IStoilov

Comment: @IStoilov  I forked your fiddle, added an override to the ajax method so that jsfiddle doesn't actually perform it, and I added a submit handler on the form so if it is submitted it will cancel it, and log that it was submitted.  As you can see from the console, the ajax is executing and the form is being submitted. https://jsfiddle.net/g0fckhjw/  If it is not working on your page, then something else is going on.

Comment: Yes, you are right. hmmm. Have no idea what can be the problem then. But thanks for your help @Taplar